# Where is preferences setting in Xamarin Studio?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-studio, region

I wanted to use VS like collapsing/expanding regions in Xamarin (5.8.3 Windows 8.1). [This](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/3549/collapsing-expanding-code-regions) post says to do it in preferences. There's nothing as such in Windows 8.1

Comment: have you tried `Tools - Options - Genaral - Enable Code folding (check=true)`

Comment: the post stated to enable collapsing to follow my previous post instructions, have you tried it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Xamarin Studio on a Mac

```
Xamarin Studio --> Preferences --> Text Editor (General) --> Enable Code Folding
```

On Windows use `Tools --> Options` instead of Preferences